# How can I change color of specific card in recyclerview after receiving certain data from mysql database column

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-recyclerview

How can I change the color of specific card in recycler view after receiving certain data from MySQL database column?

Let's say I have four cards representing different columns in the database and on receiving their state from MySQL for a specific card if true shall turn RED. If for four rows in database 2 rows depict the data as true then only two specific cards must turn RED.

```
@Override
public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View iteView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sec_sensors, parent, false);
    UserViewHolder viewHolder = new UserViewHolder(iteView);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final UserViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final UserDetails2 userDetails = secDetailsList.get(position);
    holder.tvName.setText(userDetails.getName());
    holder.tvAddress.setText(userDetails.getAddress());

  //Starting a new thread for continuously invoking database data.

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                UserLoginFunction(userDetails.getAddress());

  // Setting color for card layout to RED but not the specific card.

                holder.cards.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }
    }).start();

    View v1 = View.inflate(context, R.layout.fragment_home, null);
    lights = v1.findViewById(R.id.lights);

    holder.ivMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final UserDetails2 userDetails = secDetailsList.get(position);
            final int userId = userDetails.getUserId();
            dbHelper = new UserDatabaseHelper2(context);
            db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.myPopup);
            PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(wrapper, holder.ivMenu);

            menu.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu);
            menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.delete:
                            db.delete(UserDatabase2.TABLE_NAME2,UserDatabase2._ID + " = " + userId,null);
                            notifyItemRangeChanged(position,secDetailsList.size());
                            secDetailsList.remove(position);
                            notifyItemRemoved(position);
                            db.close();
                            new Security().mCount--;
                            break;
                        case R.id.update:
                            Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("USERID", userId);
                            context.startActivity(intent);
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            menu.show();
        }
    });

/*  holder.motionoff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
  {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(holder.motionoff.isChecked()) {
                UserLoginFunction(userDetails.getAddress());
            }
            else
            {
                UserLoginFunction(userDetails.getAddress());
            }
        }
    });*/
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return secDetailsList.size();
}

public class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView tvName, tvAddress;
    ImageView ivMenu;
    CardView cards;
    public ToggleButton motionoff;

    public UserViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        motionoff = itemView.findViewById(R.id.motion_off);
        cards = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        tvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sec_tv1);
        tvAddress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sec_tv2);
        ivMenu = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sec_iv_menu);
    }
}

// This class Asynctask retrieves data from Mysql... 

public void UserLoginFunction(final String email){

    class UserLoginClass extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {

            super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);

            if(httpResponseMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, httpResponseMsg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Not found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            hashMap.put("email",params[0]);
            finalResult = httpParse.postRequest(hashMap, HttpURL);
            return finalResult;
        }
    }

    UserLoginClass userLoginClass = new UserLoginClass();
        userLoginClass.execute(email);
}
```

Comment: its a bit hard to understand, are the cards the Items in your recyclerview adapter? do I understand correctly that you want some items but not all to turn red when some callback is executed? you talk about columns in your database but i guess you mean rows right?

Comment: See I have a column named status in let's say four individual rows. Now when the status of the second row is true then card number 2 shall change to RED. Cards are items in recyclerview.

Comment: so for that you would follow my answer below. let me maybe expand it a littl e bit based on the info you are giving me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you want to happen can be achieved with the `notifyDataSetChanged();` metod that you can call anytime on your adapter. you should write `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` at the moment that you get the new data from your mySQL DB.

it will basically reexecute `onBindViewholder`.
then you just need to put some logic into `onBindViewholder` so that your items turn red whenever the condition for them to turn red is fulfilled

So based on what you are saying Do the following:

1. whenever the data in your database changes you need to update the data in the `secDetailsList` in your code. When this happens you must also call the `notifyDataSetChanged();` (either from within or from outside the adapter)
2. in your onBindviewholder method you need to evaluate if the condition for the item being red is true:

   `if (userDetails.getRowStatus)` `{holder.cards.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.RED);}`

that way the color will change whenever the data arrives

Comment: But if I get (userDetails.getRowStatus)==TRUE for let's say 3rd row and then I call holder.cards.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.RED) then how will the 3rd card get RED. I mean will the condition be checked automatically for all the items in database?

Comment: it gets red because then you have to call notifyDataSetChanged() and by calling this method the entire onBindViewholder method gets reexecuted, taking into account the changed data. it doesnt happen automatically, it happens whenever you call notifyDataSetChanged(). so you need to call this method each time your data changes (i.e. some user gets his status set to true)

Comment: Thanks, I used a similar notifyItemChanged(position).

Comment: yes, that one is actually better as it lets you make use of some nice animations and will only redraw the affected item